# Ошибка чтения из Json файла c# mvvm

Tags: c#, json, mvvm

Всем привет с:
При первой компиляции у меня создается пустой файл json куда будут записаны данные из класса

Класс Json

```
    {
        public ObservableCollection<AdditionalParametrs> Open(string filename)
        {
            ObservableCollection<AdditionalParametrs> items = new ObservableCollection<AdditionalParametrs>();
            DataContractJsonSerializer jsonFormatter = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ObservableCollection<AdditionalParametrs>));
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
            {
                items = jsonFormatter.ReadObject(fs) as ObservableCollection<AdditionalParametrs>;
            }
            return items;
        }
}
```

Класс AdditionalParametrs

```
public class AdditionalParametrs : Model
    {
        private int id;
        private string title;
        private string type;
        private string additionalList;
        private List<string> additionalListArr;
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                id = value;
            }
        }
        public string Title
        {
            get { return title; }
            set
            {
                title = value;
            }
        }
        public string Type
        {
            get { return type; }
            set
            {
                type = value;
            }
        }
        public string AdditionalList
        {
            get { return additionalList = "Список..."; }
            set
            {
                additionalList = value;
            }
        }
        public List<string> AdditionalListArr
        {
            get { return additionalListArr; }
            set { additionalListArr = value; }
        }
    }
```

Конструктор в котором вызывается метод

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IFileService fileService)
        {
            this.fileService = fileService;
            DataList = fileService.Open(fileName);
        }
```

Я получаю ошибку "System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: "Ожидается элемент "root" из пространства имен "".. Обнаружен "None" с именем "", пространство имен "". ""
тк в файле отсутствуют "[", "]" скобки говорящие что это list типа AdditionalParametrs, моя ошибка в неверной серелизации?

Comment: Чет я не пойму, а к чему такие сложности? Ваш код открытия можно (и нужно) переписать в одну строку, где будет вызов всего двух методов... Также, я думаю, вы смешиваете VM/M и DTO в одно целое, ведь `ObservableCollection` в Model... ну, странное решение, ведь он оповещает интерфейс об изменениях данных, а это ответственность VM. Также вы (де)сериализируете целую Model в JSON, у которой наверно будет своя логика, методы и прочее.

Comment: Файл пустой, данных в нём нет. Отсюда и ошибка.